# Selenium - Difference between WebDriver.findElement() and WebElement.findElement()

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I was using `WebElement.findElement(By.cssSelector('')).click();` to find an element on a page , but it returned `"Unable to locate element"`,  But when I used `WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector('')).click();` then it was able to find the element and clicked on it.

I am unable to understand the difference between the `findElement()` of the two interfaces.
Kindly Help.

Comment: those who suggested the edits ... can you please suggest some differences also !! :P

Comment: **WebElement** and **WebDriver** are interfaces which contain abstract methods to be overridden by the class which implements them. The way you are using them doesn't make sense. Can you please provide the code you have been using to implement the above ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WebElement.findElement()` will use the element as the scope in which to search for your selector. This means it is generally used for searching for child elements.

`WebDriver.findElement()` will use the driver (i.e the entire page) to search for your given selector.

So for your instance specifically (and we'll need more information to figure it out more accurately) it's more than likely your selector doesn't match anything that is a child of your given `WebElement`, but when the `driver` tries to search for it in the entire page (excluding iframes), it can find it.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver represents your browser and WebElement represents individual elements present on web page.for better understanding can u provide your code.