# Python Selenium given an element, find elements below direct children using element.find_element

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, element

I am trying to limit the scope of a search to all nodes within a particular element. I would prefer to do this by searching via `element.find_element_by_CSS_selector`. However it seems that searching with this method will only give me the direct children of that element, not those two or more levels down. Based on what I read in this question: [Selenium - Difference between WebDriver.findElement() and WebElement.findElement()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882604/selenium-difference-between-webdriver-findelement-and-webelement-findelement)
Children *only* appears to the the expected/correct behavior.

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to limit the scope of a "find element" search using a **given web element object**. Something like `driver.element.find_element_by_CSS_selector`. Perhaps there is a way using Xpath?

*I'm still learning the terminology. I apologize if I am not correct in my usage of elements, nodes, levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.find_element_by_CSS_selector` - in this case you can find any children of `element` (any level)

`element.find_elements_by_xpath` - also can be used for searching children of `element` (don't forget to start xpath with `.`, otherwise, you will search element in whole page, i.e. `element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input")`)